# How to Push the screen up when the edit text gets the focus

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard

I have a register screen with  many fields the problem is after the third field the keyboard hides the bottom edit text and it's only showing on clicking next on the keyboard,i want to push screen up as the user navigate to the fields how can i achieve this

Answer (score 1):

You can add **"adjustResize"** to your Manifest file to resolve such kind of issue -

```
<application ... >
    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" ... >
        ...
    </activity>
    ...
</application>
```

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

Add following line in your `activity` of `AndroidManifest` file

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"`

`stateVisible` add this only if you need to appear keyboard when screen open